# Jquery terminal force scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-terminal

I'm trying to implement Jquery Terminal on my web application, but every time when I reload the page, the scroll position automatically change to terminal view. I would like to remove this “feature”, but I can't find the attribute in the documentation. My code below:

```
var term = $('#terminal').terminal(function(command) {}); 
term.echo("Hello world")
```

Comment: Im using this library: https://terminal.jcubic.pl

Comment: what do you mean with _"scroll position"_? I didn't correctly understand the core of the question. Usually scroll position means the coords at which an element is located relative to the scrolling state. By I didn't get the part _"automatically change to terminal view"_

Comment: By default, jQuery Terminal is autofocusing, which makes it jump to the terminal on opening the page. All you need is an option `enabled: false`. I should probably make it disabled by default, but right now it's hard to change. Because it would be a huge breaking change. I can document better.